# Menu goes through H2 on browser resizing

Tags: css, menu, padding

I've got a header with an h2 and a menu. The menu should always stay on the right in every resolution. But when I resize my window (to change the resolution) the menu goes right through the H2. Any idea's how to solve this? I've been looking at this for over 3 days now.

Any help much appreciated!

Here's some code:

http://jsfiddle.net/JHJcQ/

This is the CSS from my menu:

```
#headermenu .menu-primary-menu-container {
width: 749px;
float: right;
right: 3%;
position: relative;
bottom: 50px;
```

To see it in real life: http://nickdaelemans.be/wordpress/

Try resizing the browser and see what happens

I'm sorry, I'm all quite new to this! Thanks

Comment: Um, code would be helpful

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome! Please would you post your code (preferably in a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net). You may also find this super helpful for asking questions in future: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

add `min-width` tag for your header in your css script.

Generally to avoid these type of problems whole page is divided into div containers. One should put all his page contents in a big containder and give it certain properties like margin, padding, position and in your case min-width. Try adding given CSS.

Sorry was out for a moment.
Here's your code.

Find it on http://fiddle.jshell.net/qpqZs/
And try to use tags in CSS neatly. Remove extra classes you've never used.

```
<div id="container">

<div id="headermenu">
    <h2 >FASHIONFABRICE</h2>
    <div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="primary">
            <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101"><a href="http://nickdaelemans.be/wordpress/">About</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item current_page_parent menu-item-100"><a href="http://nickdaelemans.be/wordpress/?page_id=8">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://nickdaelemans.be/wordpress/?page_id=9">Styling</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-98"><a href="http://nickdaelemans.be/wordpress/?page_id=10">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="http://nickdaelemans.be/wordpress/?page_id=11">Follow Us</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="http://nickdaelemans.be/wordpress/?page_id=12">Press</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="logo">
    <img src="http://nickdaelemans.be/wordpress/wp-content/themes/follow-me-darling-child/img/FashionFabrice Logo.png" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried inserting your whole content in a div tag? and apply this min-width to that container. I dont know your code format. Try using this min-width for your body tag. I was having the same issue. Resolved it. See testnzip.comli.com for examlpe

Comment: That works! But I rather make it kind of responsive. Is there a way the menu gets smaller, so it doesn't makes the user to scroll horizontally?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JHJcQ/2/ This? if this not helps well change #container{
    min-width:749px;
}
 to fit your windows.

Comment: I think that is just isn't possible to locate the menu on the right without having to scroll horizontally, don't you think?

Comment: can you send me the files?

Comment: I don't know if it would work then, it's a wordpress website.

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!Eh1ymJiC!Q_sW82LJ2nXL0CJtEY97_VDV2XAZR3Ft3MaDEzZDbN4
Here's a zip file from all the theme pages

Comment: Yes, but it isn't what I'm looking for. I just need a responsive solution, so my menu looks good on every resolution, so it needs to be on the right of the title on every resolution without having to scroll horizontally. Maybe breaking it up into 2 lines or something, because it's just to big. Have tried resizing the fontsize of the title, but that doesn't look pretty either. Maybe you've got an idea?